# Can I use the secrets module with a version of Python earlier than 3.6?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, python-3.6, backport

Python's [`secrets`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) module was introduced in version 3.6. I'm working on an application using Python 3.4. Is there a way I can import the secrets module in a 3.4 environment (*a la* `from __future__ import print`)?

If not, is there a 3rd party module with comparable functionality?

Comment: Usually there's a backport available on pypi, but not this time it seems.

Answer (score 1):

A backport of the `secrets` module for Python versions 2.7, 3.4 and 3.5 now exists: the (somewhat confusingly named) [`python2-secrets`](https://github.com/scaleway/python2-secrets).

Installation:

```
pip install python2-secrets
```